# Maintaining the geostructure when indexing a geodataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, geopandas

I'm having a bit of trouble extracting a single point from a GeoDataFrame in pandas/geopandas.

In fact if I use a single index (using iloc or ix) the function returns a pd.Series file, and I therefore lose all the attributes and methods.
This is what I'm talking about:

```
>>> type(OMS)
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
>>> type(OMS.iloc[2:3])
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
>>> type(OMS.iloc[2])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Is there a way to efficiently extract one geometry without changing data structure/type?

In particular I need to apply the buffer method (that exists in both GeoDataFrame and GeoSeries classes) on that extracted point.

Thanks!

Comment: `OMS.iloc[2:3]` or `OMS.iloc[[2]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double brackets:

```
OMS.iloc[[2]]
```

Comment: That works! thanks!
Although I cannot understand how... are why forcing the index to be a list, and therefore the iloc/ix return a GeoDataFrame (multiple entries vs one single entry)?

Comment: When you select a single column from a dataframe Pandas automatically turns the return into a Series.  So, around is to a single column in a list and Pandas retains the DataFrame.  Or you could slice your columns using 2:3.  Or you can do OMS.iloc[2].to_frame().